# My special animal

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, geometry, computer-puzzle

The answer to this puzzle is an image not hosted on Imgur. The image host and the ID of the image on that host should become clear when solving the puzzle.

[image]
([SVG source of the above](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/247802651096514560/855720375388471316/puzzle.svg))

Exact coordinates of the 90 points as CSV:

```
n,x,y
1,-9.346534028704902,20.440528709897414
2,12.711229496645323,-21.386162697352994
3,5.462672679126538,3.4608396520779934
4,7.404602704933907,-4.245207846368064
5,22.378528444818635,-11.142966236172038
6,0.7059562512131166,18.98977341129688
7,-15.546883773426718,5.552478501494367
8,-12.761791777999258,-14.08266306257529
9,-21.24274605629696,3.4719222924921027
10,17.84440545333335,16.630402342350138
11,-2.46225681421857,2.5266864255095207
12,20.986065691171035,-13.190403973957814
13,-6.1212387275663005,-8.839444337209446
14,-11.029057005375869,22.362369968459774
15,-3.116747668651257,-16.67614545049367
16,-3.6938743922012023,-24.622617923936826
17,7.774564414644807,-5.33749545832487
18,24.97099276931516,-0.03967182097783706
19,23.653514453279016,8.063212038330583
20,-0.29143233980869354,-7.991818868742051
21,14.332075585886464,-18.80263283740173
22,-12.451040712241937,12.378705154974462
23,-24.493982898792815,-3.744185859532216
24,-7.546458950763647,23.63524196688499
25,2.564484007083731,18.63423923516268
26,16.9967951439653,-18.19081684380268
27,-11.451756666122238,-22.141734454122194
28,13.69590840004659,-17.88682226613765
29,5.524720528830471,18.179436987663458
30,15.733848289251256,-19.29359560596077
31,19.714375216659555,14.446447556249701
32,-24.819918521258572,1.7683903572102153
33,-5.780927172196478,0.25850207680830906
34,14.398167550986784,-17.16726694870563
35,-14.189611282529881,1.5010571619896993
36,-2.0716820159072498,24.912769304982262
37,24.774625947749385,2.385598001418966
38,3.2566960706745647,-7.039231055281579
39,-18.078323691229205,-11.510247758379514
40,5.538368481568888,-0.29455126787221886
41,-21.328555088247487,10.890648348473881
42,23.983852631278403,-5.3716522311537425
43,-4.820119131188136,20.105586356724984
44,15.494307211560304,19.16409425132499
45,-4.623225573900836,-11.392659676855194
46,-0.8163622314884158,10.541761812998097
47,-9.66624581813729,9.793157405843651
48,23.196079166071286,9.13268270943891
49,4.557951585109784,23.993787762530282
50,-23.438164624306694,7.789721045307999
51,-4.680749336527249,-24.457744309754403
52,21.905915195381823,11.673029483149172
53,22.579126148726374,-10.041708886031842
54,-19.71762350242226,-14.874346585546714
55,-19.782667652809664,15.026410670410584
56,-23.77025685738869,-7.051161312171757
57,1.6791611543267777,17.298111440360593
58,-11.531338390776126,11.941131407423669
59,4.322690542735046,-24.505905511275017
60,9.406439903579198,-22.677718930652457
61,12.097603769417276,21.21736709962758
62,13.000038358297118,9.303397541717281
63,-10.062428957216735,-7.370476395338589
64,-12.67976154939317,3.2725914071071394
65,17.90730535977027,-7.120756998749563
66,-22.209180484989798,6.443754638337474
67,-3.3478220124433022,-21.474879920217653
68,-2.6265807344212675,-24.703865867692308
69,23.68496062170165,-6.453898469202905
70,-20.688143523740838,-13.620070203153158
71,-12.319896909109447,-21.633263688476802
72,-17.33212126634561,17.802079672814514
73,16.03039206116207,1.6217989385232165
74,-13.712716362667132,20.36867814289814
75,7.613478587644522,-16.7977695625818
76,-20.667916734962418,9.058155372090717
77,9.302641370529777,22.592133509522668
78,-21.510237138145488,-2.6584898306642053
79,7.2640230689313015,23.37873751793868
80,-9.500748615522205,-2.309742687412623
81,3.40228192741829,3.9518257208121703
82,14.148987826245666,-7.909891201110078
83,-6.652103933564323,-23.99290346918245
84,-0.9654484541148278,-24.732114938513686
85,-21.358448734277683,-12.321906843657196
86,-8.715790384488066,15.775375653062284
87,-1.048793965997877,1.1550275127299692
88,-1.394140667988431,-8.881352643499216
89,-2.7897020225570515,-1.2320359388899185
90,-18.897700394572514,-15.927967519564376
```

*Bonus:* Why the s'more with three diamonds, lyre and three candies?

---

> Both pictures at the bottom are rebuses cluing how to parse the 90 points as a whole to get a binary string – somewhat like connect-the-dots.

Comment: I believe that `computer-puzzle` is a relevant tag, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first rebus, figured out by Feryll, is a hint to:

> Take the convex hull of the points.  This gives us a picture like this:
> [image]

The second rebus shows:

> Labeling each point on the convex hull a `1` and each point in the interior a `0`.  This gives us the following string:
> `01001 00001 01010 10110 00110 11001 11000 11000 01010 00111 11011 10011 10000 00111 11000 01010 00111 00001`

Then, based on the Morse code deciphered by Feryll, we are supposed to:

> Break the binary into groups of 5 (`18 GROUPS OF 5`) as shown above and decode using Baudot encoding.

This is clued by the axis labels and the first half of the Morse code:

> "X&Y" and `ALBUM COVER` are a reference to the [Coldplay album "X&Y"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X%26Y), whose album art contains a message in Baudot code.

The result is the string:

> `DERPIBOORU2579473`

Then using Feryll's correct identification of the image hosting site in question, one can convert this to a URL and obtain the following image:

> [image: A Beautiful Mare]

This is:

> Parcly Taxel's OC, and therefore their "special animal."

Answer (score 3):

Observations so far:

> The dots and dashes around the border of the dot-diagram is Morse code, meant to be read counterclockwise : ALBUM COVER 18 GROUPS OF 5. The "18 groups of 5" referring, presumably, to some way to partition the 90 dots in the diagram.

> Concerning the s'more, the arrow pointing to the cracker and the yellow wave must only be referring to [Graham scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan), a means of computing the border points of the convex hull of a given set of points. This must relate to how we are to process the 90 given dots.

> The diamonds in the s'more together with the "18 groups of 5" gave me idea of computing the convex hulls of point clusters 1-5, 6-10, 11-15, ..., 86-90, and seeing if a pattern emerged; perhaps each cluster's convex hull would form a quadrilateral (diamond-shaped), and we were to then to arrive at a sequence of 18 numbers, one from each cluster lying inside the 4-gon? Alas, that is not the pattern that arose; that procedure gives us 3 triangles, 9 quadrilaterals, and 6 pentagons, with no obvious relations between them:
>  [image] Perhaps this just means that the grouping into fives isn't so obvious as 1-5, 6-10, .... I wrote a program that brute-forces an 18-fold equipartition of the points such that the resulting convex hulls are all quadrilaterals, but if that is truly the way forward, such an equipartition is not at all unique; here is one at random:
>  [[1,7,67,79,87],[2,32,35,37,83],[3,29,40,48,56],[4,11,22,26,34],[5,38,43,60,89],[6,21,23,69,73],[8,30,42,66,90],[9,19,25,49,58],[10,45,68,71,88],[12,15,47,54,84],[13,27,62,64,77],[14,59,74,75,86],[16,18,20,33,53],[17,24,57,61,76],[28,44,63,65,78],[31,46,52,55,81],[36,39,41,51,85],[50,70,72,80,82]]

> In other words, I am at a loss what the diamonds in the s'more really mean to say, or indeed the basket with the lyre and the candies. What I *do* know is that they are the cutie marks of the characters [Rarity](https://mlp.fandom.com/wiki/Rarity) (diamonds) and the popular couple [Lyra (Heartstrings) and Bon Bon (Sweetie Drops)](https://mylittlebrony.fandom.com/wiki/Lyra_and_Bon_Bon) from the MLP universe. This leads me to believe the image hosting site we seek is likely derpibooru.org (or somewhere similar), where recently posted images are at this point identified with a 7-digit ID in the url.

> It should be noted the dots in the lower right roughly outline the shape of the basket via their convex hull, and the circled 1 is at the starting point for a Graham scan.

> The 90 dots have an unusual tendency to lie very close to (but never exceeding) r = 25.