# This'll Keep 'Em Busy

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

But for how long? Let's take it from the top!

[image]

Be ready to allocate upwards of 16.7KB of memory for this task, you eager beavers you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is hinted

> from the words "busy" and "beaver" that the image is a depiction of a Turing machine (a [busy beaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) is a halting 2-symbol Turing machine printing the most ones). The markings on the ends of the edges denote various aspects of the transition (no flipping!) [image]

> Number the states 0 to 5 starting from the top and going clockwise. The transitions are given below in (old state, old symbol, new symbol, movement direction, new state) format:
> (0,0,1,L,1)
> (0,1,1,L,0)
> (1,0,1,R,2)
> (1,1,1,R,1)
> (2,0,0,R,5)
> (2,1,1,R,3)
> (3,0,1,L,0)
> (3,1,0,R,4)
> (4,0,0,L,0)
> (4,1,1,R,2)
> (5,0,1,L,4)
> (5,1,halt)
> We start at state 0 ("take it from the top").

Now

> when [implemented in C++](https://gist.github.com/Parcly-Taxel/c85f8d283e59d40a43e584c658de6bff) the above Turing machine halts after **13,122,572,796 steps**, which is how long they'll be kept busy for. **204,918 positions** are used, of which **136,610** are ones.

Comment: All correct! I took the Turing machine from [this page](http://turbotm.de/~heiner/BB/simmbL6_1.html) (itself from the "Historical Survey of Busy Beavers"), and I actually realize now that my "1.7KB" clue was off by a decimal place (thankfully it's more just a retrospective easter egg); I've fixed it to be 16.7KB (as that is approximately how much information is contained in 136,612 bits, although of course any implementation will likely in practice need more like your 204,918 figure).

Comment: @Feryll hey, I'm a brony [too](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/110546/75318). Is there a way we could keep in touch?

Comment: Consider it done :)

Comment: Ah, beat me to it - I was running it on a simulator but had to let it run overnight. Nicely solved!

Comment: @Desuovi My code took less than two minutes to find the solution. I thought this was going to be much lengthier than lunch, but I was wrong.

Comment: Huh! Then I guess the program I used was poorly-optimized - I found a program online to run it rather than writing one myself.